# How to map caps lock key to esc in visual studio code vim extension?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I see a lot of answers to this question that aren't related to mac, and still couldn't quite figure it out on my machine.

I previously worked on Ubuntu and migrated to a MacBook. I used the settings sync extension to bring my keybindings and extensions together.

I have so far

1. mapped the caps lock key to esc at system level
2. checked the `extension.vim_escape` shortcut is set to caps lock on vscode
3. in my `keybindings.json` file I currently have

```
{
  "key": "capslock",
  "command": "extension.vim_escape",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
},
{
  "key": "escape",
  "command": "-extension.vim_escape",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
},
```

also, could this be related to gitlens perhaps?

```
 {
    "key": "capslock",
    "command": "gitlens.key.escape",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && gitlens:key:escape && !findWidgetVisible && !isInEmbeddedEditor && !renameInputVisible && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "-gitlens.key.escape",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && gitlens:key:escape && !findWidgetVisible && !isInEmbeddedEditor && !renameInputVisible && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
```